# Open Office regular expression to remove everything in brackets?

Tags: regex, openoffice

I have a huge, long list in Open Office Writer and I like to remove some parts of the text, but manually it would take days.
Can anyone tell me how to make a regular expression to remove everything between brackets in the text?
Here's the example. The text now looks like this:

word word word (number word)
word word (word word)
numbers word (word number word)
word (numbers)
etc....

I would like it to look like this:

word word word
word word
numbers word
word
etc....

So I would like to remove everything from brackets + the brackets themselves too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do a line by line search and remove the brackets. See the example I've [cooked up here](http://pythex.org/?regex=(.*)(%5C(.*%5C))&test_string=word%20word%20word%20(number%20word)%0Aword%20word%20(word%20word)%0Anumbers%20word%20(word%20number%20word)%0Aword%20(numbers)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). You can use many online regex tools to try this

This is the regex i came up with. I don't have openoffice so can't test it in that.

Assuming this is the screen you are looking at:

[image: screenshot]

This regular expression should work

```
(\(.*\))
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. Your example does find each line that contains words inside brackets and if I use "find&replace with", it removes them but it also removes everything before and after the brackets too. I need something that only removes the words inside brackets but leaves everything else before and after them.

Comment: [screenshot](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Finding_and_replacing) is this the correct screen? If so then just try this `(\(.*\))`

Comment: You are welcome, will edit the answer to reflect the changes